# MS Access sorting

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-order-by

I have a table that stores my staff information. I would like to sort them by their ranks which do not follow the ASCII or alphabetical order.

For example, SO stand for senior officers, ASO stand for assistant senior officers, and O stand for officers. I would like to sort them in the order like: SO -> ASO -> O.

I am wondering is there a way I can achieve that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what we need. You can edit your question with details of the exact problem you are having, what you have tried to solve it and your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can help.

Comment: How can you identify the categories by which you want to sort?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a conditional expression in the `order by`.  For instance:

```
order by switch(rank = "SO", 1, rank = "ASO", 2, rank = "O", 3, 1=1, 4)
```

Or using nested `iif()`:

```
order by iif(rank = "SO", 1
             iif(rank = "ASO", 2,
                 iif(rank = "O", 3, 4)
                )
            )
```

Or, have a reference table with the ordering values and join it it:

```
select t.*
from t inner join
     ranks as r
     on r.rank = t.rank
order by r.ord;
```